# How to kill process completely from a thread in Linux (C)

Tags: c, linux

I have a C code that runs on Linux that creates a certain amount of threads. In one of the threads, I want it so that if it runs into a certain condition, it should terminate the entire process. I looked up the exit() command but didn't really understand how to use it.

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's little not to understand about `exit()`. Just do:

```
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

and gone's your process.

`EXIT_FAILURE` becomes the exit status of your program; this is the same as returning a value from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're all in one process, though multiple threads, just hitting exit will kill the lot.